# form post is empty - no data submitted - when opened in new tab

Tags: php, html, forms

User are complaining about my form submits, they are not working. I couldn't reproduce this behaviour by normal usage. By accident I found a way to reproduce the error. If I click the submit button using `CTRL + Left Mouse Button (aka open in new Tab)` the POST-Data is empty:

**OUTPUT**

```
Array
(
)
ERR: !array_key_exists('firstname
ERR: !isset(['firstname
ERR: strlen(['firstname
ERR: !array_key_exists('lastname
ERR: !isset(['lastname
ERR: strlen(['lastname
ERR #001.
```

**HTML**

```
<form action="form.php" method="post" target="_blank">
    <input type="text" name="firstname" value="123">
    <input type="text" name="lastname" value="123">
    <input type="text" name="age" value="123">
    <button id="btnsubmit" type="submit">Submit</button>
    <button type="reset">Reset</button>
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
new CSVMailer();
class CSVMailer
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->postData = $_POST;

        // check if redirects are set. mandantory. otherwise die.
        if (!array_key_exists('firstname', $this->postData) || !array_key_exists('lastname', $this->postData)) {
            $this->debug($_POST);

            if (!array_key_exists('firstname', $this->postData)){ $this->debug( "ERR: !array_key_exists('firstname'" . $this->postData); }
            if (!isset($this->postData['firstname'])){ $this->debug( "ERR: !isset(['firstname" . $this->postData); }
            if (strlen($this->postData['firstname']) < 1){ $this->debug( "ERR: strlen(['firstname'])" . $this->postData); }

            if (!array_key_exists('lastname', $this->postData)){ $this->debug( "ERR: !array_key_exists('lastname'" . $this->postData); }
            if (!isset($this->postData['lastname'])){ $this->debug( "ERR: !isset(['lastname" . $this->postData); }
            if (strlen($this->postData['lastname']) < 1){ $this->debug( "ERR: strlen(['lastname'])" . $this->postData); }

            print "Error #001.";
            die();
        } else {
        }
    }

    public function debug($obj)
    {
        $date = date('Y/m/d H:i:s');
        file_put_contents('csv.php.log', $date.' '.$obj . "\n", FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);

        print '<pre>';
        print_r($obj);
        print '</pre>';
    }
}
```

I don't know what user do while submitting. Is it possible that some browsers on Desktop/Mobile Devices behave different or might any kind of extensions like ad-blocker or something will make the form `open in a new tab`? If so, it would confirm my thoughts.

I have no idea how to solve this right now.

**Update #1:** This behaviour seems to be only for Safari. I can't reproduce the error using chrome or firefox right now.

Comment: Do you have any of these users' contact information in order to find out more? Your first step should probably be to verify that you're fixing the problem they're having, rather than another problem altogether, which may or may not be the case here

Comment: Opening up a form in a new tab will open the page with a GET request, it will not POST the form.

Comment: @MayorofthePlattenbaus I rarely got a reply while contacting and asking for some information. Those few who answered said they "just filled out the form and submitted it". Usually I asked to try a different browser and never heard anything again.

Comment: @aynber i just found out it does work on firefox and chrome